# Why does sleep 1 | vim file break shell?

Tags: vim, pipe

While testing piping on a shell that I wrote, I noticed that the command

```
sleep 1 | vim file
```

causes text written to stdout to be misaligned in subsequent commands. At first I thought that this was a bug in my shell but then I noticed that it has the same effect in other shells like bash and zsh. Why does this happen?

Comment: Looks like `vim` fails to restore the terminal settings on exit for some reason. You can reset them manually with `reset`.

Comment: Did you notice the `Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal`? Vim depends on having access to terminal input and output. If that isn't given, all bets are off. (Sorry, I don't know more details, therefore not an answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Vim needs a interactive stdin (from shell).

```
sleep 3; vim file
```

If you dont need the input or:

```
vim <(sleep 3; ls)
vim -d <(ls) <(ls -a)
```

If you need it. Warning: no space between < and (

See more there: https://askubuntu.com/a/510907/360110